# Run unit tests against two different injected dependencies

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, junit4

I have two service beans in my application which both implement an interface. For that interface, all methods must perform the same (tho the internals differ).

So I'd like to write one set of tests that runs against both services. (Don't wanna write duplicate code)

What's the best way to structure my tests to accomplish this?

(I've tagged junit4, since that's the version to which I'm currently limited.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answers here were all great, but didn't exactly fit my preferences.
I ended up going with a combination of

- JUnit's `@RunWith(@Parameterized)` (to run the tests for both services)
- Spring's new Rules (to keep the `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` container, appcontext, webmvc and injection functionality)

Here's the snippets:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)

...

@Parameters(name = "Cached = {0}")
public static Boolean[] data() {
    return new Boolean[] { Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.FALSE };
}

@ClassRule
public static final SpringClassRule springClassRule = new SpringClassRule();

@Rule
public final SpringMethodRule springMethodRule = new SpringMethodRule();

@Before
public void setUp() {
     // logic to choose the injected service based on the true/false param
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a bean that holds the list of implementations in JavaConfig:

```
public class TestConfig {

    @Bean
    MyService myService1(){
        return new MyService1();
    }

    @Bean
    MyService myService2(){
        return new MyService2();
    }

    @Bean
    public List<MyService> myServices(MyService myService1, MyService myService2){
        List<MyService> allServices = new ArrayList<>();
        allServices.add(myService1);
        allServices.add(myService2);
        return allServices;
    }
}
```

And eventually iterate this list in your test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=TestConfig.class)
public class ServicesTest {
    @Autowired
    private List<MyService> allServices;
    @Test
    public void testAllServices(){    
        for (MyService service : allServices) {
            // Test service here
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

few options:

1. You could store all classes in a constant like `List<Class<? extends YourInterface>> classes = Arrays.asList(Implementation.class)` loop through these classes and call the method for each
2. You can use Reflections to find all the classes implementing a certain interface and loop through for each class.

Answer (score 0):

You could have an autowired list of your services and loop through and test each implementation as some have suggested. But I would say this is actually not a great solution for a number of reasons:

- If any one implementation fails then it is possible that another is broken and you wont know till you run the test again with the bug fixed
- It is better to have many more very simple tests than less tests which do more as it makes it more difficult to track down failures.
- Need Spring - this point might not matter but it can be advantageous to not rely on all these constructs if at the very least to reduce the amount of your system you are testing

You could get all fancy with type parameters and inherit from a generic base class like `class BaseTest<HW extends HelloWorldInterface >` with an `@Autowired HW hw`, and then simply extend this class with `class HelloGermanyTest extends BaseTest<GutenTag>` where `GutenTag implements HelloWorldInterface`.

But I have tried this and I have found it simpler to simply write assert functions against an interface as follows:

```
public static void assertImplementationSaysHelloWorld(HelloWorldInterface hello, String expectedResult) {
    assertEquals(expectedResult, hello);
}
```

There is much less going on and the function is much more reusable than inheritance. For instance if I have a class that implements more than one interface, with the inheritance method I would be force to write more classes to test each interface. Whereas I can use as many different assert functions as I want in one test class.